# jQuery Animate function not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement the animate function on a div, where the text expands a little when the mouse is hovered over it and then goes back to its original size when the mouse leaves.

Right now with my code, each time I hover the mouse over it, it just keeps on shrinking into a tiny rectangle. What am I doing incorrect?

```
    <script>
    $(function () {
        var container = $('div.slider').css('overflow', 'hidden').children('ul'),
            slider = new Slider(container, $('#slider-nav'));

        slider.nav.find('button').on('click', function () {
            slider.setCurrent($(this).data('dir'));
            slider.transition();
        });
    })();

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        //var dd = $('dd');
        //dd.hide();

        $('dd').filter(':nth-child(n+4)').hide();
        $('dl').on('click', 'dt', function () {
            $(this)
                .next().hide()
                .slideDown(200)
                //.show()
                .siblings('dd')
                .slideUp(200);
            //.hide();
            //$(this).next().show(); 
        });
    })();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#admission').on('mouseenter', function () {
            $(this).animate({ 'fontSize': '+=2', 'height': '+=25', 'width': '+=20' }, 'swing')
        });
        $('#admission').on('mouseleave', function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({ 'fontSize': '-=2', 'height': '-=25', 'width': '-=20' }, 'swing')
        });
    });
</script>
```

The last `<script>.... ('#admission')..` code is the one with the issue.

Comment: It was working for me earlier in the day as well, but not don't know why it decided to go bonkers on me.

Comment: May I ask why you're using jQuery for something like this? You could do this with a simple `:hover`-property in CSS.

Comment: I think the problem is the `.stop()`. If you hover multiple times before the previous animation has finished this stops the previous animation in the middle, and then the next animation begins *from the current size*. If you animated to a specific size rather than using `+=2` and `-=2` that might fix it, because then future animations wouldn't keep building on aborted past ones. Or use `.stop(true,true)`, on both enter and leave, though [that gets a bit jerky](https://jsfiddle.net/Larw3rc7/1/).

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I have to use jQuery to do some sort of animate function in the project. I thought of something this simple.

Comment: Ah, okay - well, then you have an okay solution.

Comment: @nnnnnn I took out the `.stop()` and tried animating it to a fixed size, but still the same issue. Does it matter if I another slider script running before it?

Answer (score 0):

I modified like this and it's works fine.

```
$(function() {
        $('#admission').on('mouseenter', function () {
            $(this).animate({ 'fontSize': '+=2', 'height': '+=25', 'width': '+=20' }, 'swing')
        });
        $('#admission').on('mouseleave', function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({ 'fontSize': '-=2', 'height': '-=25', 'width': '-=20' }, 'swing')
        });
    });
</script>
```

The ready function needed the $ and little reformatting and there was an extra () couple of parenthesis at the end.

Comment: I don't know why it still doesn't work. I have edited my post with all the script statements I am using in the page. Just to see if that could be the issue. The first 2 scripts functions are working, but not the last one.